# Get centroid of a polygon and transform pixel coords with X,Y coords

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, shapely

Is there a way to get the coordinates of the centroid of a polygon and transform them into latitude and longitude?

I am using Shapely to convert contours into polygons from Google Satellite images. I also have the latitude and longitude of the center of the shape I want to convert into a polygon.

I was thinking of extracting the centroid coordinates of the converted polygon and then transform them into whatever CRS I want, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Can somebody suggest anything?

Answer (score 4):

1. Reproject the data frame
2. Apply centroid method

`df.to_crs(epsg=4326).geometry.centroid`